# .ctp file with utf-8 character in name cannot be found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm working with CakePHP 2.3.

In the routes file, I have included something like this:

```
Router::connect('/thomas-lammle', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'thomas-lämmle'));
```

I want the .ctp file it's displaying to be named this name including the dots over the a, so that the automatically generated page title will appear correctly.  On one server I've tried, it works fine, but on another, it throws the following error:

```
Missing View
Error: The view for PagesController::display() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: /www/test_site/public_html/app/View/Pages/thomas-lämmle.ctp
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_view.ctp
```

Of course the file named thomas-lämmle.ctp exists on both servers, and it's strange because I cannot tell why it's even reporting that the file is missing, when the name appears to match the file that definitely exists.  Could it be something with my apache settings?  If so, could this be fixed by changing the .htaccess file somehow?

Comment: I personally try to prevent this kind of file names because some servers don't handle them well. In your case the easiest workaround would of course be to rename the file (as a bonus, it then also matches the requested URL in your route :))

Comment: @thaJeztah Yeah, that's what I ultimately ended up doing because I don't have direct control over the problem server.

Comment: Sometimes that's just the best approach, although it *should* be possible with UTF8 file names. Might be a bug in CakePHP or a configuration of the server or PHP, code page conversions in PHP can be a pain in the *ss to debug.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the file-related APIs of most high-level languages delegate to the underlying C implementation, which in turn uses the `LANG` variable to convert textual filenames to binary streams. By default *system* programs are started with `LANG=C`, which means characters (the ones you see in your file manager or your console) are encoded as ASCII, while *user* programs use some variant of utf8, like `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` - at least this is what I found in most Ubuntu installation, but what is *user* and what is *system* is obviously an implementation detail.

If you want to use Unicode text for filenames you must ensure that

1. the apache process is started with the *right* `LANG` (you can check the environment variables from PHP with [`getenv`](http://www.php.net/getenv) and make quick experiments with the filesystem). The *right* LANG is the encoding you used when first creating the file
2. the right character is passed to the CakePHP router (which seems the case from your report, but still).